# Computing the dimensions of an isosceles trapezoid only knowing one base, its angles, and the area

Tags: geometry, area

[image]

Is it possible to compute b and c's of an isosceles trapezoid given values for area (A), one base (a), and the angle off of that base (α)?  I thought I could break this down into determining the area of the 2 right triangles made up from from c, height, and (b-a)/2, but I got nowhere fast with that approach.

Comment: Of course, it is possible. $b=a-2c\cos\alpha$, $h=c\sin\alpha$, $S=\frac12 (a+b)h$. Then solve quadratic equation for $c$ and there will be only one positive root.

Comment: The "$S$" in Ivan Karnacheyeu's comment is the area $A$ in your problem.